# Visual Studio will not check out a file when editing!

Tags: visual-studio-2008, version-control, tfs

I'm using VS2008 SP1 and TFS 2008 for version control.

The other day, I had a merge conflict in a `.sln` file when doing a Get-Latest. I resolved the conflict, and all appeared to be well.

Now however, the VS2008 source control integration has gone wrong.

What used to happen when editing a non-checked out file was that VS2008 would silently check out the file, and allow me to edit.

Now what happens is that I attempt to type in a non-checked out file, and well, nothing happens. VS does not check out the file, so it remains read-only, and none of my key-presses result in any action.

I have followed the instructions [in this other seemingly-related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302700/visual-studio-2008-will-not-edit-read-only-files) but it does not help.

I've also tried deleting and re-creating from scratch the original `.sln` file that had the merge conflict, but this did not help either.

Note: If I manually find the file in the solution explorer, right click and 'check out for edit' then I can edit the file. Doing this for every single file however is a bit ridiculous.

Please help!

Comment: Just to cover all ground: if (and only if) you have a 64-bit OS, when you applied the registry fix in the answer that you've linked to, did you account for that in registry path and inserted a "Wow64" node there?

Comment: I'm on XP 32 bit, but good thinking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tracked it down to a WIX project I had in the solution (I have Wix3.0.5217.0 (RC2)).

The wix project had a project reference to a project file which I removed as part of an earlier checkin. I didn't realise this (another developer had been editing the wix project).

I removed the invalid project reference from the Wix project, reloaded the solution, and it all appears to be working again. Hooray!